# docx output in huxtable ignores set_font setting

Tags: r, fonts, docx, flextable, huxtable

Outputting a `huxtable` (`huxtable` version `5.4.0`) to a `docx` seems to ignore the font that has been set via `huxtable::set_font()`. On my system I get an output in font "DejaVu Sans".

```r
library(magrittr)
library(huxtable)

ht <- huxtable(column1 = 1:5,
               column2 = letters[1:5]) %>% 
  set_font("arial")

quick_docx(ht, file = "hux.docx", open = FALSE)
```

As it turns out, transforming the huxtable to a flextable via `huxtable::as_flextable()` and then setting the font via `flextable::font()` works (`flextable` version `0.6.6`).

```r
ht_flex <- ht %>%
  as_flextable() %>%
  flextable::font(fontname = "arial")

flextable::save_as_docx(ht_flex, path = "hux_flex.docx")
```

I would, however, prefer if I could get the job done purely with `huxtable`. Am I missing something or is this something specific to my system setup?